# Create ranking within set of rows resulting from GROUP BY

Tags: python, sqlite, count, window-functions, dense-rank

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE "results" (
    "player"    INTEGER,
    "tournament"    INTEGER,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    "course"    INTEGER,
    "round" INTEGER,
    "score" INTEGER,
);
```

With the following data sample for a single `tournament` / `year` / `round`-combination.

```
1  33  2016  895  1  20  
2  33  2016  895  1  10
3  33  2016  895  1  25
4  33  2016  895  1  28
7  33  2016  895  1  25
8  33  2016  895  1  17
9  33  2016  895  1  12
```

I would like to create a new column called `ranking` that represents the ranking of the player for that particular `tournament` / `year` / `round`-combination. The player with the most points is #1. If players score the same, they are tied which needs to specified with a "T".

The desired output looks as follows:

```
1  33  2016  895  1  20  3
2  33  2016  895  1  12  T5 
3  33  2016  895  1  25  T2
4  33  2016  895  1  28  1 
7  33  2016  895  1  25  T2
8  33  2016  895  1  17  4
9  33  2016  895  1  12  T5
```

How can I achieve the above?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` window function to do the ranking and `COUNT()` window function check if it is needed to concatenate `'T'` at the start:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tournament, year, course, round, score) > 1 THEN 'T' ELSE '' END ||
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tournament, year, course, round ORDER BY score DESC) AS ranking
FROM results
ORDER BY player;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Vq8Rh3e).

If `course` is not important for this ranking then remove it from both `PARTITION BY` clauses.